# How to convert a dictionary with keys of type of tuple to a list of dictionaries in python?

Tags: python, pandas, list, numpy, dictionary

I am using `pandas` and `numpy` libraries, to calculate the **pearson correlation** of two simple lists. The output of the below code is the matrix of correlation:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])
y = np.array([2, 1, 4, 5, 8, 12, 18, 25, 96, 48])
x, y = pd.Series(x), pd.Series(y)
xy = pd.DataFrame({'dist-values': x, 'uptime-values': y})
matrix = xy.corr(method="pearson")
```

After using the `.unstack()`, and `.to_dict()` functions on the output we can have a dictionary in the below format:

```
result = matrix.unstack().to_dict()
# {('dist-values', 'dist-values'): 1.0, 
#   ('dist-values', 'uptime-values'): 0.7586402890911869, 
#   ('uptime-values', 'dist-values'): 0.7586402890911869, 
#   ('uptime-values', 'uptime-values'): 1.0}
```

But I need to convert it to a list of dictionaries, and the output should be like this:

```
#[  {'f1': 'dist-values', 'f2': 'dist-values', 'value': '1.0'}, 
#   {'f1': 'dist-values', 'f2': 'uptime-values', 'value': '0.7586402890911869'}, 
#   {'f1': 'uptime-values', 'f2': 'dist-values', 'value': '0.7586402890911869'}, 
#   {'f1': 'uptime-values', 'f2': 'uptime-values', 'value': '1.0'}
# ]
```

What's the best and efficient way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What about:

```
result = (matrix.unstack().rename_axis(['f1', 'f2'])
                .reset_index(name='value').to_dict('records')
          )
```

output:

```
[{'f1': 'dist-values', 'f2': 'dist-values', 'value': 1.0},
 {'f1': 'dist-values', 'f2': 'uptime-values', 'value': 0.7586402890911869},
 {'f1': 'uptime-values', 'f2': 'dist-values', 'value': 0.7586402890911869},
 {'f1': 'uptime-values', 'f2': 'uptime-values', 'value': 1.0}]
```

Comment: can we use the `rename_axis` function if we had another feature and the third key like `f3`? I have changed the code to `rename_axis['f1', 'f2', 'f3']`, but it shows this error: `ValueError: Length of names must match number of levels in MultiIndex.`

Comment: You need as many names as there are levels in your index. Where is the third key coming from?

Comment: Yes, you are right, that was my fault. thanks.